# How to use abstract method TreeModel in zk framework?

Tags: java, zk

My question just very short.**"How to use abstract method or example used in this method?"**

This method is from org.zkoss.zul.TreeModel

```
  tmtAtasan = new TreeModel<Map<String,Object>>() {

        @Override
        public void addTreeDataListener(TreeDataListener arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> getChild(int[] arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> getChild(Map<String, Object> arg0,
                int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public int getChildCount(Map<String, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public int getIndexOfChild(Map<String, Object> arg0,
                Map<String, Object> arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public int[] getPath(Map<String, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> getRoot() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isLeaf(Map<String, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void removeTreeDataListener(TreeDataListener arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

I am badly stuck into this. Any help would be really appreciateable.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/MVC/Model/Tree_Model

Comment: What do you want to do? If you just want to use a basic TreeModel call the DefaultTreeModel constructor instead.

Comment: I want to make Hierarchy employee data with Tree, the data from ArrayList. I don't know how to make it. can you tell me how? or an example similar with that. Thanks for answer ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from what I understand you just want to use a generic TreeModel without needing to redefine specific behaviors.

So let's imagine your model is a list of Employee beans like :

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private List<Employee> listSubordinates = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public Employee(String pName) {
        name = pName;
    }

    public void setName(String pName) {
        this.name = pName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Employee> getListSubordinates() {
        return listSubordinates;
    }
    public void setListSubordinates(List<Employee> pListSubordinates) {
        this.listSubordinates = pListSubordinates;
    }
}
```

For this example, we'll imagine you have retrieved a list of employee that are sorted by hierarchy already (to simplify the example).

```
Employee boss1 = new Employee("Boss1");
Employee sub1 = new Employee("Sub1");
boss1.getListSubordinates().add(sub1);
Employee sub2 = new Employee("Sub2");
boss1.getListSubordinates().add(sub2);

Employee boss2 = new Employee("Boss2");
Employee sub3 = new Employee("Sub3");
boss2.getListSubordinates().add(sub3);

List<Employee> listBosses = Arrays.asList(boss1, boss2);
```

Again this is a simple example with just one level of hierarchy, if you had a variable level of hierarchy the following code would have to be recursive.

```
// Build the list of the nodes sorted by hierarchy
List<DefaultTreeNode<Employee>> firstLevelNodes = new ArrayList<DefaultTreeNode<Employee>>();
// For each employee of the highest level
for (Employee boss : listBosses) {
    // Build the list of its sub employee
    List<DefaultTreeNode<Employee>> listSubordinates = new ArrayList<DefaultTreeNode<Employee>>();
    for (Employee subordinate : boss.getListSubordinates()) {
        listSubordinates.add(new DefaultTreeNode<Employee>(subordinate));
    }
    // Then build the boss node with its data and its children nodes
    DefaultTreeNode<Employee> bossNode = new DefaultTreeNode<Employee>(boss, listSubordinates);
    // And add it to the list of first level nodes
    firstLevelNodes.add(bossNode);
}

// Build the ROOT, a 'technical' node containing the nodes of the tree.
DefaultTreeNode<Employee> root = new DefaultTreeNode<Employee>(null, firstLevelNodes);
// Create the TreeModel
TreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel<Employee>(root);
```

And now you just have to set the TreeModel to your Tree component.

Hope this helps.